# What is direction of torque in an IC engine?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Apologies if my question is silly, but I still hope some of you will help me out. Based on  my reading about torque from Wikipedia
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque
Torque should be in perpendicular direction to force and radius vectors.
In case of an Internal Combustion  engine, what is direction of torques produced. If crank shaft is rotating radially , won’t the perpendicular force generated by torque want to moves crank shaft sidewise-perpendicular. Apologies if couldn’t convey my question correctly I have tried adding one more wiki link to demonstrate crankshaft in action
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crankshaft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the front of an engine, most engines produce a clock-wise torque due to the side the crankpin is when the power stroke occurs.

[image: fig1]

On each of the pistons that undergo combustion above it, the line of action of the force $F$ going through the connecting rod is offset to the crankshaft main axis by some radius $r$. This is the perpendicular distance of the conrod axis to the main crank axis.

The torque produced by that piston at that moment is $T = r F$.

If you look at a slider-crank mechanism, you realize that the gas forces $P$ and the side load $S$ combine to produce the crank force $F$.

[image: fig2]

What is missing from the diagram above is the friction due to the side load, which is the most significant source of torque loss due to friction in modern engines.

Comment: I do not believe this is what the OP is asking due to the phrase "*Torque should be in perpendicular direction to force and radius vectors*" which brings clarification to the OP's confusion terminology of what perpendicular or side-wise perpendicular is supposed to mean (since there are two perpendicular directions to every vector). It draws attention away from the operation of a real engine to the math vectors involved in describing torque. In that sense, the first diagram is really misleading since it follows the left-hand convention which no one uses.

Comment: @DKNguyen - I agree I messed up the direction of the torque arrow on the first diagram. I am going to try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your phrasing about directions and such are very confusing but I think I understand what you are trying to ask.

It sounds like you're confusing the *mathematical representation* of torque with the physical direction of the rotation that the torque produces.

Think of a broken clock with an arm in the 3 o'clock position. Pushing straight downwards at the tip of the arm applies a force that produces a CW torque (let's think of it as a circular arrow pointing CW. You can imagine it's very difficult/inconvenient to mathematically represent a circular arrow.

Instead, what we do is pick a convention: the right-hand rule. Curl your fingers in the direction of the circular CW arrow. What direction is your thumb pointing? It is pointing straight into the page. So we use the arrow that points in the direction of your thumb to represent the torque. Now the torque is represented by just one arrow that never changes direction. Much simpler and we find math to make it work properly so things makes sense.

There is no force going into the page. There is no force acting in the direction of your thumb. it's just a simple mathematical way for us to represent to the CW direction of the actual torque which would be difficult do directly since the circular arrow doesn't have just one linear direction.

The only real force I actually talked about in this entire example was the force at the very beginning when you pushed the tip of the arm straight down.

Comment: I tried rephrasing and added another wiki link showing crankshaft in action

Comment: @SohailKhan Still not clear, but try reading what I wrote. Pretty sure that's what you're wanting to know.

Comment: I am still struggling to understand, apologies. While tightening the screw, are we applying torque on the head of screw resulting in downward force (assuming clockwise rotation) I am thoroughly confused with difference between force and torque and their directions, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @SohailKhan Screws are wedges in spiral form so applying a force in one direction exerts a force in the other. Don't think about them here. It's not the same thing. The torque vector is a mathematical way to keep track of the torque. It is not the actual torque so don't think the arrow's direction is the direction of anything real. It's like writing down that you have 5 apples in your book. The writing that says "5 apples" aren't the actual apples. It's just a way to keep track of them.

Comment: @SohailKhan Correct. Nothing actually travels in the direction of the vector representing the torque. Screws are spiral wedges so there's more going on there. Don't think about them for now. I suppose the torque vector and the torque are different in the same way that five real apples are different than the text "5 apples" in your log book. One is the real thing, the other is a representation used to keep track of it. In that sense, it is wrong to say that the torque in a clock points into the face of the clock. The torque VECTOR points into the face of the clock. [cont...]

Comment: Thanks a lot Now i understand this topic really appreciate your help

Comment: But the real torque is clockwise, producing an effect as if you had a bunch of linear force pushing tangent to a circle centered on the center of the clock.